# How to create and use a list of items that are instances of a class

Tags: c#, list, loops, data-structures

I'm looking for a simple way to store and access `Iteminfo`.

I have a Database with a Table with the following data: `ItemId`,`uItemname`,`Itemname`,`ItemDesc`,`ItemSize`; usually 20 records but can be more.
The problem is I don't know how to create a structure that supports multiple Items that can easily be read.

What I am looking for is a structure that can create `Items` that are easily read and can be created within the code.

Example:

```cs
public class Item
{
     public int ItemId {get; set;}
     public string uItemname {get; set;}
     public string Itemname {get; set;}
     public string ItemDesc {get; set;}
     public float ItemSize {get; set;}
}
```

And inside the code I want to make a new one like

```cs
Item.Add(0,"test_item","Test","TestDesc",22.5f);
```

And when I ask something I need a way to access it like:

```cs
foreach(Item i in Item//IDk how to access all Created)
{
  if(i.Itemname == "Test")
  {
     print(i.uItemname +"|"+ i.ItemSize);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out generic collections like the [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).

You can add items easily like this

```
var listOfItems = new List<Item>();
var yourNewItem = new Item {
    ItemId = 0,
    uItemname = "test_item",
    Itemname = "Test",
    ItemDesc = "TestDesc",
    ItemSize = 22.5f
};

listOfItems.Add(yourNewItem);
```

And iterating through the list is done via foreach

```
foreach (Item i in listOfItems) {
  if(i.Itemname == "Test")
    print(i.uItemname +"|"+ i.ItemSize);
}
```

Comment: And how do i get for example the Value uItemname inside the foreach (to use in a "if")

Comment: _string uItemName = i.uItemName;_ The get a list of all uItemNames you could use _List<string> uItemList =_listOfItems.Select(d => d.uItemName).ToList();_ for instance, if you like to use Linq. I would recommend to work through some learning material, as this is quite basic.

Comment: You would get any value of your item just like you did in your own example foreach-loop. You already mentioned the proper way to do that.

Comment: Ok got it, but what variable type do i use to save them outside the scriptcode, inside the main class to use in diffent codeblocks. var is not possible || @DanielSchmid i learn by doing stuff i never done, just try and repeat

Comment: using _var_ would work if the compiler can deduct the type from the variable assignment e.g. _var ItemList = new List<Item>();_. That's a shortcut of _List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>();_